# How to store VB.Net Generics in a .Net Generic

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, inheritance, collections

I have a VB.Net Generic like this

```
Public Class typeableDictionary(of T as baseClass)
    Inherits System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(of String, T)
    ...
End Class
```

with (for example) the following classes destined for storage therein:

```
Public Class derivedClass1
    Inherits baseClass
    ...
End Class
```

and

```
Public Class derivedClass2
    Inherits baseClass
    ...
End Class
```

This is instantiated in various places in my code - eg:

```
Public typedDictionary1(of derivedClass1)
Public typedDictionary2(of derivedClass2)
```

My question is simple: how can I store these, where T is different for each member, in the **same** Dictionary i.e.

I've tried

```
Private dictionaryStore as New Dictionary(Of String, typeableDictionary)
```

but obviously this fails to compile is it doesn't understand `typeableDictionary` on its own and expects `typeableDictionary(Of <Type>)`.

I've also tried the clumsier

```
Private dictionaryStore as New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, baseClass))
```

and this also fails.

The specific need here is to store several dictionaries of types derived from the same base class (generic) in a single Dictionary, from which they will be retrieved later and handled in type-specific ways.  I could of course declare a separate dictionary for each type, but this lacks elegance and I am sure there is something in the power of VB.Net that lets me solve this much more easily.

Am I missing something obvious here?  It's making my head hurt so far!  In fact I was hoping that by typing my question, I would understand it better and maybe StackOverflow would identify a similar question but so far I am not sure it has.

Do I need a further layer of abstraction??

Comment: Does having a non-generic base class help here. I.e. TypeableDictionary<T> : TypeableDictionary. Then you use a Dictionary<String, TypeableDictionary>.

Comment: Thinking that generic classes with different T's are related is a very common mistake.  The only base class they have in common is System.Object.  You're a *little* ahead here, you got the non-generic IDictionary in common by accident.  And yes, it is not typesafe.  It can't be.

Comment: @HansPassant - so is it correct to say that the compiler doesn't "look through" a derived class to determine its base class?  Seems this would be a very useful area for the .Net/VB.Net team to expand, if so.  Also Hans I'd like to "up arrow" your response, but (since it's in a comment) I can't...

Comment: It is correct to say that the compiler enforces type safety.  That's it job.  Nothing much you can hope for from the VB.NET team, this is all very much by design.  You can learn more about it by googling ".net generics covariance".

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to declare your typedDictionary with an interface instead of a class.  Is this what you had in mind?

```
Public Interface IBaseClass
    Sub GetResult()
End Interface

Public Class typeableDictionary(Of T As IBaseClass)
    Inherits System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, T)
    REM some code here
End Class

Public Class DerivedClass1
    Implements IBaseClass

    Public Sub GetResult() Implements IBaseClass.GetResult
        Console.WriteLine("This is DerivedClass1")
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class DerivedClass2
    Implements IBaseClass

    Public Sub GetResult() Implements IBaseClass.GetResult
        Console.WriteLine("This is DerivedClass2")
    End Sub
End Class

    Sub Main()
        Dim myTypedDictionary As New typeableDictionary(Of IBaseClass)
        myTypedDictionary.Add("1", New DerivedClass1)
        myTypedDictionary.Add("2", New DerivedClass2)
        Console.WriteLine("this is a vb app")
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `derivedClass1` and `derivedClass2` should either inherit from a base class or implement a common interface.  Then you define your dictionaries as 
`typeableDictionary(Of baseClass)` or `typeableDictionary(Of yourInterface)`.

You need to change

```
Public typedDictionary1(of derivedClass1)
Public typedDictionary2(of derivedClass2)
```

to

```
Public typedDictionary1 As typeableDictionary(of baseClass)
Public typedDictionary2 As typeableDictionary(of baseClass)
```

Comment: That's what (I think) I've done but it fails to compile:      Error 60 Value of type 'ReferenceData.referenceDataNameDictionary(Of T)' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, referenceDataBase)'. C:\...Data\ReferenceData\referenceDataService.vb 112 62